# Expected value of lottery drawing by using the Indicator Random Variable?

Tags: probability, statistics, expected-value

The question states: 
In a lottery $5$ numbers are chosen from the set $\{1,..,90\}$ without replacement. We order the $5$ numbers in increasing order and we denote by $X$ the number of times the difference between two neighboring numbers is $1$.

I included a picture of my attempt and I think I might've messed up since the numbers are ordered.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mMYJr.png)

Answer (score 0):

Order cannot matter: it affects the numerator and denominator by the same factor of $5!$

So an expectation of $(5 \times 4)\times \dfrac{89}{90\times 89} = \dfrac29$, which is what you found, looks correct